# AspxPageControl Tabs with Web Pages

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net project about dynamic tabs and I want show my web pages that I designed before in this tabs.

I'm using ASPXPageControl on my page for that. But I couldn't make showing pages on my ASPXPageControl tabs. Tabs show nothing.

How can I do this? It is ok for me if there any other way.

Thanks in advance.

This is my button that creates new tab

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Text = "tabtext";
        tab.Name = "tabid";

        var ctrl = new LiteralControl("<iframe src='http://www.w3schools.com'></iframe>");
        ctrl.ID = "controlid";
        tab.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);

    }
```

And design

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <dx:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" EnableCallBacks="True" EnableClientSideAPI="True" Height="265px" OnActiveTabChanged="ASPxPageControl1_ActiveTabChanged" OnActiveTabChanging="ASPxPageControl1_ActiveTabChanging" RenderMode="Lightweight" Width="726px">
            <TabPages>
                <dx:TabPage Text="Sekme 1">
                    <ContentCollection>
                        <dx:ContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                            hello
                        </dx:ContentControl>
                    </ContentCollection>
                </dx:TabPage>
                <dx:TabPage Text="Sekme 2">
                    <ContentCollection>
                        <dx:ContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                    <%--this is works when I comment out. But I want dynamic pages--%>
                    <%--<iframe src="Default.aspx" runat="server" id="frm2" style="width:99%; height:78vh; margin-top:20px;">

                    </iframe>--%>
                        </dx:ContentControl>
                    </ContentCollection>
                </dx:TabPage>
            </TabPages>
        </dx:ASPxPageControl>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: I just wanted an idea but if it works I added